# ROS Answers SE migration: node not found

Tags: ros, catkin-make, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros-users,
I downloaded package youbot_navigation for ros-hydro. I compiled it with catkin_make without error but when I try to run the lowpass_filter get
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [youbot_navigation_common/lowpass_filter]: can't locate node [lowpass_filter] in package [youbot_navigation_common]
even if the node is correctly compiled with catkin_make:
[ 15%] Built target lowpass_filter

the launch file is: roslaunch youbot_navigation_local move_base_local.launch

The complete output of catkin_make is:

raffaele@raffaele:~/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws/install

Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws/build"
Running command: "make -j6 -l6" in "/home/raffaele/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws/build"
[ 0%] [ 0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 7%] [ 23%] Built target listener
Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target lowpass_filter
[ 46%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 76%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 76%] Built target beginner_tutorials_gencpp
[ 76%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
[ 84%] Built target talker
[ 92%] Built target add_two_ints_server
[100%] Built target add_two_ints_client
raffaele@raffaele:~/ros/hydro_node/catkin_ws$

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173543/node-not-found/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-06-13**:
Hi Rahndall, can you edit your post to give us the complete output of catkin_make?
And which launch command are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

try

```
# In your catkin workspace
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ source ./devel/setup.bash
```

and then run your program.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works :) Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) with karma: 133 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1